# Introducing a PvP tag for WoW

Tags: discussion, tags, sub-tags

I think that there should be a PvP tag for World of Warcraft, [wow-pvp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wow-pvp) or [world-of-warcraft-pvp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft-pvp).

There are currently [77 questions regarding PvP in WoW](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=world-of-warcraft+pvp), showing that there is a lot of interest. In-game, PvP and PvE require differing approaches, meaning that a question warrants a different answer in a PvP context than out of it. Also, I personally have wanted to use such a tag but, seeing that there was only a [world-of-warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft) tag, I was forced to clarify my interest in a PvP-related answer in the question title.

Answer (score 5):

I see no problem with a [world-of-warcraft-pvp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft-pvp) tag, as it is a well-defined subset of WoW at large.

Do note, however, that if you were to use it, you would still need to include the [world-of-warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft) in all relevant questions. (Similar to [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone) and [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft))