# Should [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server] always be used with [minecraft-bedrock-edition]?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft, sub-tags

The tag wiki excerpt for [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server) was recently edited to strongly recommend also using [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition). There's a similar suggested edit for [minecraft-java-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-server). (For transparency, I rejected the latter edit with the intention of building consensus with this meta post.)

This seems strange to me for two reasons:

Firstly, having a tag that always requires another tag seems superfluous. Surely the more specific tag would imply the more general one? If this relationship is important, it can be expressed in the tag wiki.

Secondly, [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) seems more appropriate for questions regarding the game itself, with [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server) seeming more appropriate for questions related to server setup and administration, as well as questions about how the dedicated server works.

For example, *[Does time pass on a Minecraft SMP server if nobody is logged on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27557/does-time-pass-on-a-minecraft-smp-server-if-nobody-is-logged-on)* seems like a good example of a question which is solely concerned with how the dedicated server behaves, and I would expect it to only need [minecraft-java-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition-server).

On the other hand, *[How can I join servers in PS4 Bedrock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363495/how-can-i-join-servers-in-ps4-bedrock)* seems like the opposite problem -- the question itself does not obviously relate to dedicated servers, and I'd expect it to only need [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).

Should *every* [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server) question really also be tagged with [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)?

In visual terms, which of these two images makes more sense, or do we need to find a middle ground?

[image: Old Arqade Categories] or [image: test]

Comment: So the question is whether the tags should be treated standalone (like [Fortnite's game modes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12982/28182) or [GTA 5 vs Online](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7760/28182), as opposed to treating them as [meta-tag:sub-tags], like [minecraft-commands], [tf2-spy] etc? There's definitely precedent for both.

Comment: @Penguin no worries, I just saw the edit in my queue and didn't think it was as clear cut. the outcome of this post may very well be that we re-make your edit anyway :)

Comment: Related: [Inconsistency in Minecraft related tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15697/250180)

Comment: When is this considered a "consensus"? Does an answer have to achieve x upvotes before we can start doing it?

Comment: @Penguin The short answer is, it depends. The long answer is, [it depends](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177550/). I'd say right now we have not achieved consensus: the highest upvoted answer is at +1, with a 60% upvote ratio. Plus, new answers were recently written; I don't think we lose anything by waiting a little longer and figuring out as a community what approach we would like to collectively take. After all, the action of updating the wiki and adding tags is easy! (The action of removing tags is somewhat harder, since a blanket removal of a tag might not always make sense.)

Comment: [Guess what I found.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5230/258509) At that point there wasn't even a bedrock edition, just a bunch of extremely new different platform-specifics that no one was really asking about yet. It's the same idea with different tag names

Comment: By the way, I assume consensus here (when it's reached) can be used for [tag:minecraft-x-realms], [tag:minecraft-x-server], [tag:minecraft-mods], and [tag:minecraft-addons]? Those are all version exclusive btw

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 i more meant that using the tag with the version it implies (i.e. java realms implies java edition, or mods implies java edition) would be done according to consensus here at the original question

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 reread what i said. [tag:minecraft-x-realms]. Not [tag:minecraft-realms]. I meant each edition

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 no, I'm saying that the consensus here should also determine consensus for [tag:minecraft-mods] and [tag:minecraft-addons]

Answer (score 5):

*Please wait 5–15 seconds for the images on this post to load. I'm afraid I can't upload them to SE Imgur because the files are `.svg`.*

**I'd like to copy my answer from [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15697/250180) because I believe that it is applicable to this question too.** In summary, *neither solution proposed here is correct.* Instead, I propose merging the two server tags into `[minecraft-servers]`.

If you don't believe that this answer is also applicable here, feel free to leave a comment.

---

For those of you who haven't read [my profile page](/users/250180/expertcoder14?tab=profile) yet, I am an administrator on the [Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes Wiki](https://ktane.fandom.com/wiki/User:ExpertCoder14) on Fandom. I have dealt with a similar issue on my wiki before involving categories, which act like tags on our wiki.

There are two ways to classify modules in KTaNE: whether they are from the vanilla game or modded, and whether they're regular or needy. At first, I made the following categories:

[image: Old KTaNE Wiki Categories]

That looks fine and dandy, but I noticed a flaw with this setup. There is, in reality, no need for this extra segregation between different categories. A setup that combines categories like this would actually be better:

[image: New Categories]

With this second setup, it is actually better than the older setup because of overlapping categories. This allows us to search questions better, because it allows us to narrow down our search by specifying more than one category. *It's like the difference between Gmail and normal email.* Mail only allows one folder for each item. Gmail allows multiple. **We allow multiple tags on our posts. Let's take advantage of that.**

For example, to get a search of all modded needy modules, you would use a search like: `[mod-modules] [needy-modules]` to get a list. This should be the same on Arqade, where *the more you specify in the search*, the *narrower your results get*. This is not the case in the first example, where specifying just one tag would get results too narrow.

Say you wanted any regular modules, no matter the origin. With the first example, you would need to do `[regular-modules] or [mod-modules]` which does not make sense from a searching perspective. **We're a knowledge base, not a forum, just like my wiki. Therefore, our site and its tags should be optimized from a searching perspective, not an asking and answering perspective.** Search engines give you stuff on topics similar to your actual destination, unless you explicitly ask to exclude them.

Now we're back to the original problem with our server tags. Neither of these two graphics are the best solution:

[image: Old Arqade Categories] or [image: test]

The best solution would look like this:

[image: New Arqade Categories]

With this improved setup, if you search `[minecraft-servers]`, you'll get questions on all types of servers, Java, and Bedrock. Only want the Java servers? Add `[minecraft-java-edition]` to your search. Want Java gameplay questions that are not about servers? Simply use the inversion: `[minecraft-java-edition] -[minecraft-servers]`. **We have a search function that will let us specify the exact combination of tags that we want. Let's take advantage of it.**

So I'm sorry to [Fabian Röling](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/171580) for undoing one of [your proposed changes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14812/250180), but I think that this would greatly benefit us to change the tags so that the search can run the way it's supposed to.

---

I understand that some users may be angry because that increases the potential for a user specifying [minecraft-servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-servers) without specifying their edition, like with [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands). To combat this problem, I have made [this feature-request](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15699/250180).

Comment: Wait you can add any url source into your images? That doesnt sound good 

Comment: no not you using it, I just mean that being a feature in general seems like a bad idea since then anyone can just start grabbing IPs

Comment: "We allow multiple tags on our posts. Let's take advantage of that." Good sentence that tells me the opinion I was struggling to get across.

Comment: I don't see a real benefit of this compared with my solution. If I adapt the crux of your answer to mine: "*With this setup, if you search [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server] and [minecraft-java-edition-server], you'll get questions on all types of servers, Java, and Bedrock. Only want the Java servers? Search for [minecraft-java-edition-edition]. Want Java gameplay questions that are not about servers? Simply use [minecraft-java-edition].*" As you can see, the exact same amount of tags is needed. The additional benefit is that the editing involved would not be nearly as extensive.

Comment: Additionally, the Gmail comparison, i.e. the 'cross-sorting' of questions, is an inherent part of tagging already (e.g. [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server] and [minecraft-java-edition-server]).

Comment: Okay, I see your point, and get the appeal. Will it be worth the trouble of retagging, though?

Comment: Haha, yes, you're right (and, by the way, in case that's helpful, Gimp can open .svg files :).

Answer (score 0):

Should both tags *always* be used together?

**No. There is no reason at all to use an implicit tag.**
Or, since the update with the graphic representations: **option 2**.

There are tagging cases where the more general tag (e.g. [the-elder-scrolls-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-series)) is used to address a larger, encompassing area (i.c. the lore of the series). Such a tag can be used to point out that potential answerers should look beyond the individual title (if one is mentioned at all).

The [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server) tag is not one of them, because those servers are of no importance to users not asking about the specific game (version).

This is how tagging (and the SE network) works to begin with: through overlapping areas of expertise, they narrow down the scope of the question to its core. And [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) doesn't narrow down the scope of [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server).

---

Addition, for clarity's sake: I'm *not* saying the two tags should never be used together, or that they overlap completely!
If a user has a gameplay question that applies to certain servers, of course both tags should be used, because it concerns areas that are not covered by either of the tags alone. I'm simply saying that there is no inherent reason to use both at all times.

To illustrate:
This beautiful graphic represents the two tags mentioned in the title, black for [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) and white for [minecraft-bedrock-edition-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition-server):

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vectorstock.com%2Froyalty-free-vector%2Foverlap-overlay-opacity-icon-black-colors-sign-vector-24346995&psig=AOvVaw3VfsJ_TwOTyUH4Uottlr3C&ust=1616921499283000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCPiK65CM0O8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)</sup>

My point is that **only in cases where the question's topic lies in the area where both tags overlap - in the hatched section of the graphic - the use of both tags is warranted.**

Comment: if i use the [react.js] tag on SO, I would always use the [javascript] tag. Why would this be any different? It's the same concept

Comment: as for the frst point i still disagree bc it still regards the game itself

Comment: @Penguin I also wouldn't agree with that tag combination, that seems superfluous. And I'm confused as to what you're disagreeing with, can you specify?

Comment: you should use that tag. The reason seems fairly simple (to me at least) if we think about it at an arbitrary level: A tag isn't what can narrow it down the most. A tag has multiple purposes which are for searching in search engines **and** the site. If I look at the minecraft-bedrock tag, I am not looking for only certain things. I'm looking for things about Minecraft Bedrock Edition. The tag is for all things related to Minecraft Bedrock Edition. Let's see the usage guidance...

Comment: "The version of Minecraft on iOS, Android, Windows 10, Xbox One, Nintendo Switch, PlayStation 4, Gear VR and Fire OS." No where does that imply certain questions only and it should be used as it implies, which it DOES apply to those you said not to use it on. Idc what specifically it's about if its about minecraft-bedrock you should be using that tag. That's basically what I think for both and the js - reactjs also

Comment: @Penguin Okay, that's clear, thank you. I think we can agree to disagree then :) Just for the record, I'll edit my post in case something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe it should. What's the usage guidance for [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition)?

> The version of Minecraft on iOS, Android, Windows 10, Xbox One, Nintendo Switch, PlayStation 4, Gear VR and Fire OS

Why would that not apply to a question specifically about servers (or realms if you're including that, not too sure)?

Why does the [minecraft-bedrock-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) tag exist? For questions about Minecraft (bedrock). When should I use it? For questions about Minecraft. I wrote a question about Minecraft; it's about my server. *This is where some may say no.* Why would you say no here? Does this not apply to that question? *Well yes but that's more about servers and less about gameplay -* It shouldn't matter. A tag should be added based on the following simple question: **Is it about the subject matter?** I expect to see those questions in the minecraft tag searches.